# Image_Picker Build Failed on Flutter (Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.)

Tags: android, dart, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-dependencies

I used image_picker(**^0.6.0+2**) and  image_cropper(**^1.0.1**)
when **flutter run** build failed.

```
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              

BUILD FAILED in 32s
```

I used so many thing to solve this problen.nothings working. after that I removed image_picker and image_cropper then application running perfectly.

> **IOS working fine, Android build Failed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

1. Open project on VSCode and open Android module on Android Studio and Migrate to AndroidX